How to diagram "He makes her happy"
How do I diagram the sentence:

He makes her happy.

I was going to put "her" as the direct direct object, but "he" is not making "her." I was also considering an implied "be," as in:

He makes her (be) happy.

How ought this sentence to be diagrammed?

He's having an effect on her, so "her" is the direct object. Make has many meanings.

I

He makes her happy.

This structure is of the type SVOC.
"C", the complement, is of the particular type called "object complement".
he: subject
makes : verb form
her: object
happy: object complement
A Comprehensive Grammar of the English Language, Quirk et al., § 2.16
model: Most people consider these books rather expensive.
II

He makes her be happy.

A bare infinitive clause may function as object complement with a relatively few superordinate verbs […].
